# Cambiar mensaje genérico "Transaction Aborted" en JSF2

Tags: mysql, primefaces

He desarrollado una aplicación web que registra cliente; y tengo la validación de clientes repetidos por compañía dentro de un trigger en mysql; pero a nivel del JSF necesito mostrar el mensaje genérico que desarrolle en mysql, pero solo me indica "Transaction Aborted". He revisado en otros post pero solo indican que debe sobrescribir el método create. Adjunto mi código.

**ClienteController**

```
    public void createCliente() throws SQLException{
    if (this.cliente.getId() < 0) {
        this.cliente.setNombresCompletos(this.cliente.getNombres() + " " + 
        this.cliente.getApellidos());
        this.cliente.setFechaCreacion(new Date());
        try{
        this.clienteEJB.create(this.cliente);
        this.auditCreateCliente();
        this.saveTmp();
        forUtil.showMensajeInformativo("El registro fue ingresado.");
        }catch(Exception e){
            forUtil.showMensajeError(e.getMessage());
        }
    } else {
        forUtil.showMensajeError("El registro ya fue ingresado.");
    }
}
```

**ClienteFacade**

```
    @Stateless
    public class ClienteFacade extends AbstractFacade<Cliente> implements ClienteFacadeLocal {

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "estudioPU")
private EntityManager em;

@Override
protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return em;
}

@Override
public void create (Cliente cliente){
    try{
        super.create(cliente);
    }catch(SQLException e){ //Aqui me indica que debo remover la clausula catch
        forUtil.showMensajeError(e.getMessage());
    }    
}

public ClienteFacade() {
    super(Cliente.class);
}
```

¿Cómo puedo mostrar mis mensajes creados en db dentro de mi controller?
Saludos

Codigo forUtil

```
   public static void showMensajeError(String msg) {
     FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
     FacesMessage facesMessage = new 
     FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Error", msg);
     facesContext.addMessage(null, facesMessage);
   }
```

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar el código de forUtil?

Comment: forUtil es un metodo que invoca a un FacesContext para enviar un mensaje.

Comment: Prueba a trabajar con el Throwable que ha provocado la SQLException. Dentro del catch haz e.getCause(), que es posible que te muestre la causa del error.